# How to use a Post Request in a Loop using Async

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, http, axios

I have my a get request which I'm using to fetch an array of IDs which I then use in a POST request to get the results for each ID.
How do I format this to make the POST request work?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220845/discussion-on-question-by-angela-how-to-use-a-post-request-in-a-loop-using-async).

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
            axios(config)
                .then(function (response) {
                    results.push(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

you probably want to continue using await

```
const response = await axios(config);
results.push(JSON.parse(response.data)); // not json.stringify
```

Comment: When I try to console.log the results outside of the function, nothing gets logged

Comment: Are you awaiting the async function before  trying to console.log anything? I get the feeling that the problem you're having here is in understanding the relationship between asynchronous operations and synchronous ones.

Answer (score 0):

@Angela , this is pretty simple.

First of all, you can either use `async/await` or `then/catch` methodology. `Async/await` is introduced to overcome the `then/catch` chaining issue (which is called snake code). So when your project gets larger, you hit with this chaining issue. So with `async/await` you do not need to use `then/catch`. You need to use `try/catch` with `async/await`.

I have created a sample code and repo exclusively for your requirement where I simulated your problem with `async/await. I have tested as well and attach screenshots as well in the readme. Please have a look.

https://github.com/ajaysikdar/nodejs-sample

This is how it looks. You get all the results then the only res.send will process.
`console.log("now send results by res.send")` get executed once you get all the results.

server results
[image]

client results
[image]